# Output array in Twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, longtext

I trying to output an array from the database to the screen.
In my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $category;
```

In my twig template:

```
{% for category in user.profile.category %}
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Error:  `Array to string conversion in ...`

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TWIG doesn't know how you want to display your table.

By the way, you should consider naming your variable `$categories` instead of `$category`, as you table contains several categories.

Then try this:

```
{% for category in user.profile.categories %}
   {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

If my answer doesn't help, please give us the structure of your array (is there any keys or sub-arrays in you table or is it just a list?)

Answer (score 31):

So, as error shows you are trying convert array (in `category` variable) to string. You can preview array by `dump()` ([doc.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)). In your case:

```
{% for category in user.profile.category %}
    {{ dump(category) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Please notice that `dump()` should be use only for debugging.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `join` to output an array as a concatenated string. It behaves like [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in php.

Example:

```
{{ [1, 2, 3]|join }}
{# returns 123 #}

{{ [1, 2, 3]|join('|') }}
{# outputs 1|2|3 #}

{{ [1, 2, 3]|join(', ', ' and ') }}
{# outputs 1, 2 and 3 #}
```

See the [twig join documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html).

Comment: Here the new link fot the doc : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who want to output an associative array easily :

(here, the array is user.profile.category)

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                {% for key,value in user.profile.category[0] %}
                    <td>{{key|e }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>

            {% for cat in user.profile.category %}
                <tr>
                    {% for cell in cat %}
                        <td>{{ cell|e }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Opencart 4 you need to add
**$this->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension());**

in   *public function __construct(LoaderInterface $loader, $options = [])*
**system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php**

and enable **set debug' => true,** // Initialize Twig environment

in *public function render(string $filename, array $data = [], string $code = ''): string {*
**system\library\template\twig.php**